# Converting a vector into a matrix R

Tags: r, vector, matrix

I have a vector vec of size let say n and a matrix m IxI which is full of 0 (the matrix). I want to replace the first column of the matrix by the first I entries of the vector vec, then replace the first I-1 entries of the second column of the matrix m by the entries I+1  to 2I-1 of vec, then the first I-3 entries of the third column of the matrix m by the entries 2I  to 3I-2 of vec, and so on. Is there a fast way of doing it in R? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in future we could have a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000)?

This seems to match your verbal description above:

```
n <- 5
m <- matrix(0,n,n)
m[((n+1)-col(m))>=row(m)] <- 1:(n*(n+1)/2)
m
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    6   10   13   15
## [2,]    2    7   11   14    0
## [3,]    3    8   12    0    0
## [4,]    4    9    0    0    0
## [5,]    5    0    0    0    0
```

`?lower.tri` is useful too, but I think it doesn't specify the components you want.

Comment: Yes the length match up. n= prod_{i=1}^{I}i

Comment: It almost wokrs, it just that instead of takeing the first entries of a column, it takes the last entries of a column

Comment: oops it is  n= sum_{i=1}^{I}i

Comment: Alright go it! m[(col(m)+row(m))<=(I+1)]! Thanks